# Плохо ли вам было у Плюшкина

Tags: запятые, ссп, учебное-задание

"Плохо ли вам было у Плюшкина, или, просто по своей охоте гуляете по лесам да дерете прохожих?"
Первая запятая перед "или" разделяет 2 предложения в ССП, а вторая, после "или", зачем?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Плохо **ли** вам было у Плюшкина, **или** просто по своей охоте гуляете по лесам да дерете прохожих?

**Запятая после союза  ИЛИ не нужна.**

Пояснение

1) Это сложносочиненное предложение (в него входят два односоставных предложения), разделительный союз ЛИ...ИЛИ считается повторяющимся, общая вопросительная интонация не должна учитываться, **поэтому запятая перед ИЛИ ставится.**

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133

Примечания: 1. В сложносочиненном предложении сочетание ли…или рассматривается **как повторяющийся союз** (в отличие от простого предложения с однородными членами, в котором ли…или не образуют повторяющегося союза, вследствие чего запятая перед или не ставится): **Во сне ль всё это снится мне, или гляжу я в самом деле, на что при этой же луне с тобой живые мы глядели?** (Тютч.);

2) Просто — частица?

**ПРОСТО**, проще. I. нареч. к Простой (1.П.; 1, 4, 9-10 зн.). Задача решается п. Писать п. и ясно. Смотреть на вещи п. III. частица. Разг. 1.  2. Всего лишь, всего-навсего; не иначе как. Вы п. смеётесь над нами. Всё это п. детское упрямство. Он п. не умён. **Зашёл к вам п. так** (без особых причин, целей, намерений).

Если это частица, а не наречие, то размещать после нее обособленный член вроде бы некорректно.

Если считать, что это наречие, то (кроме обособления) возможны еще и однородные отношения: просто, по своей охоте (с одной запятой).

И вывод: **Не простое это дело — классиков править.**

Answer (score 1):

Это предложение Розенталь приводит как пример сложного предложения с независимыми простыми (п.5 примеч. к "ли...или"):
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=139#pp139

> Запятая ставится, если ли…или соединяют независимые вопросительные
>   предложения: Плохо ли вам было у Плюшкина, или, просто, по своей охоте
>   гуляете по лесам да дерёте прохожих? (Г.) (см. § 30, п. 1, прим.)

Посмотрела в бумажном варианте "Мёртвых душ" из серии "Библиотека учителя"(М.,Худ.лит, 1987) - там так:

> Плохо ли вам было у Плюшкина, или просто, по своей охоте,  гуляете по
>   лесам да дерёте прохожих?

По-моему, нормальный вариант с уточнением, всё по правилам. Может, он и есть исходный? А вот справочник Розенталя у меня уже 90-х годов, там обособляется частица просто ( как пояснение), как-то не вяжется с Гоголем. Вполне возможно, это уже "творчество" или ошибка современных наборщиков, корректоров, технического редактора, не знаю ещё кого. Сейчас часто вообще никаких корректоров нет. А ошибка так и переходит из издания в издание.

Answer (score 0):

Да, одинокая, ничего не обособляющая (да и бессмысленная), запятая плоховато смотрится. Но в половине компетентных источников корректоры с редакторами нарисовали следующее (я к ним присоединяюсь):

***[Плохо ли вам было у Плюшкина или просто, по своей охоте, гуляете по лесам да дерете проезжих?](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%20-%20%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%20%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE%20%D1%83%20%D0%9F%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%2C%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%2C%20%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%85%3F&oq=%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%20-%20%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%20%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE%20%D1%83%20%D0%9F%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%2C%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%2C%20%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%85%3F&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.11231j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)***